# QML How to import ItemGrabResult?

Tags: qt, qml, screenshot

I try to use ItemGrabResult {} element. But I got error
*"QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component"
"ItemGrabResult is not a type"*

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: root


    ItemGrabResult {

    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
```

ItemGrabResult is inactive

[image]

In documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-itemgrabresult.html#details
I can not find any information how to import this element in CMake (or qmake) file

Comment: You can't instantiate an `ItemGrabResult` like that. This type is only meant to be the parameter of `grabToImage` [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method).

Comment: `ItemGrabResult` is defined as [QML_ANONYMOUS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_ANONYMOUS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As iam_peter indicated, the ItemGrabResult comes from a call to Item.grabToImage().

In the following example, you need to click on the red `Rectangle` and it will initiate a `grabToImage()` call. The callback will have an instance of the `ItemGrabResult` which has properties and methods for accessing the grabbed image:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Item {
        id: frame
        width: 200
        height: 200
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            color: "red"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                frame.grabToImage( function (itemGrabResult) {
                    // itemGrabResult: QQuickItemGrabResult(0x254f9a0)
                    // itemGrabResult.image: QVariant(QImage, QImage(QSize(200, 200),format=QImage::Format_RGBA8888_Premultiplied,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=800,sizeInBytes=160000))
                    // itemGrabResult.saveToFile: function() { [native code] }
                    dbg.text = `
itemGrabResult: ${itemGrabResult.toString()}
itemGrabResult.image: ${itemGrabResult.image.toString()}
itemGrabResult.saveToFile: ${itemGrabResult.saveToFile.toString()}
`
                } );
            }
        }
    }
    footer: TextEdit { id: dbg; wrapMode: Text.WordWrap }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method